# Redirect Url error

Tags: php, redirect

Well, a few days ago I have found some problems on a task. What I need to do is: Make sure the url is in the right format, and if it is not, redirect to the correct url. In other urls that I had no problems, but this'm having. Anyway, I will try to explain the error in the best way. I have this function in my Model to list the learnings:

```
public function get_learning_category_list() {
$categorias = $this->db->select('t1.id, t1.title, t1.metadata, t1.meta_title, t1.description, t1.meta_description, t1.meta_spam, t1.url, t1.alt_img')
        ->from('learning_category t1')
        ->join('learning_rel_category t4', 't1.id = t4.category_id', 'left')
        ->join('learning t2', 't4.learning_id = t2.id', 'left')
        ->join('learning_rel_language t3', 't2.id = t3.learning_id', 'left')
        ->where('t3.language', $this->language)
        ->group_by('t1.id')
        ->get()->result_array();
    foreach($categorias as $c){
        $total = $this->db->select('count(learning_rel_language.learning_id) as total', false)
        ->from('learning')
        ->join('learning_rel_language', 'learning.id = learning_rel_language.learning_id', 'inner')
        ->join('learning_rel_category', 'learning.id = learning_rel_category.learning_id', 'inner')
        ->where('learning_rel_category.category_id', $c['id'])
        ->where('learning_rel_language.language', $this->language)
        ->group_by('learning_rel_language.language')->get()->first_row('array');

        $metadata = json_decode($c['metadata']);
        $tt = $c['title'];
        $url = $c['url'];
        if($this->language != 'pt_br'){
            $tt = $metadata->{$this->language};
            $tt_pt_br = $c['title'];
        }

        $return[] = array('url' => $url, 'title'=>$tt, 'id'=>$c['id'], 'total'=>$total['total'], 'title_pt_br'=>$tt_pt_br);

    }
```

She will return me an Array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => [title] => Courses on how to generate qualified leads [id] => 2 [total] => 6 [title_pt_br] => ) [1] => Array ( [url] => [title] => Social Media Marketing Courses [id] => 3 [total] => 2 [title_pt_br] => )...
```

And the Model have this function that defines the format of the url:

```
 public function url_format_category($category, $lang_domin) { 
    if (lang('abbr') == 'en_US')
        $lang_domin = 'en/';
    else if (lang('abbr') == 'es_US')
        $lang_domin = 'es/';

    $categorias = $this->learn->get_learning_category_list();
    foreach($categorias as $cat){
        $cat = (object) $cat;
        if($cat->title != '') {
            $return = strtolower(url_title($cat->title)).'-cmdo-'.$cat->id;
        }else{
            $return = 'cursos-de-marketing-digital-online-'.$cat->id;
        }   
    return $return;   
    }
}
```

So far so right, he rides the url with the title and id of Learning. In my controller I have a function that checks if the url is correct and redirects:

```
    //redirect to real list_route
    if($this->uri->uri_string != $this->learn->url_format_category($category, $lang_domin)) {
        redirect($this->learn->url_format_category(),'location','301');
        exit;
        die($this->learn->url_format_category($category, $lang_domin));

    }
```

It is in the redirection error occurs, it is done according to the `url_format_category` but it always redirects to the first result of the Array (courses on how to generate qualified leads, ie always the same title) independent of the page he are.
If you have not been clear, I edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: The `foreach` loop overwrites `$return` each time through. So It will always end up with the value from the last element of `$categorias`.

Comment: Why do you set the variable `$lang_domain` but not use it?

Comment: how can I make him not overlap?

Comment: I don't know, I don't understand what you're trying to do there. Do you want to return the first item that has a non-empty title?

Comment: It is the part of the language, but I will not use it now

Comment: No, I want to return the title according to url

Comment: For example, if the page title is "Example of title" it will get the url "example-of-title".

Comment: But `url_format_category` has a list of categories, which one is it supposed to return?

Comment: The function also doesn't use the `$category` argument.